# c switch default

Tags: c, switch, case

Привет. Пытаясь ответит на один из вопросов здесь, с удивлением обнаружил, что следующий код

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 123;
    const char *r = "initial value";
    switch (a) {
        case 1: r = "1"; break;
        if (0) {
            default: r = "not 1";
        }
    }
    puts(r);
    return 0;
}
```

нормально компилируется GCC и выдает при исполнении

```
not 1
```

Мне кажется, что код явно с такой ошибкой, что даже компилироваться не должен. В чем тут дело?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тело `switch` (как и тело `while`, `do/while`, `for` и т.п) это просто statement, в котором мы расставляем метки `case` и `default`, и в котором возможно использование `break`. Не более того.

Метки `case` и `default` могут появляться только внутри statement, принадлежащего какому-то `switch`, но в остальном ограничения, накладываемые на расстановку этих меток, ничем не отличаются от любых других меток.

Аналогичным образом передача управления на эти метки происходит по правилам, похожим на правила `goto`, с той только разницей, что передать управление на метку `case` и `default` может только ее непосредственно охватывающий `switch`.

В вашем случае, если заменить метки `case` и `default` на "обычные" метки, мы получим просто составной statement

```
{
    l1:
      r = "1"; break;
    if (0) {
      l2:
        r = "not 1";
    }
}
```

Ничего необычного в этом составном statement-е нет. Положение меток в нем не нарушает никаких правил языка. В том, что метка `default:` передает управление внутрь ветки некоего `if`, нет ничего необычного.

Вас никто не заставляет даже использовать именно *составной* statement для реализации тела `switch`, т.е. вопреки распространенной практике тело `switch` не обязательно должно быть заключено в `{}`. Вы можете воспользоваться любым другим типом statament и расставить метки в нем

```
int i = rand() % 4;
switch (i)
  if (0)      case 0:  printf("Privet!\n");
  else if (0) case 1:  printf("Hello!\n");     
  else if (0) case 2:  printf("World!\n");     
  else        default: printf("Ku-ku!\n");
```

Обратите внимание, что эта замечательная техника написания `switch` избавляет вас от необходимости помнить о `break` в конце каждой ветки.

Comment: Но ведь то, что внутри if(0) - не должно выполняться. А оно выполняется.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Что значит "не должно"? Если вы передали туда внутрь управление при помощи `goto` или `switch\case` в обход проверки условия `if`, то оно будет выполняться. Куда ж оно денется-то?

Comment: Вот уж действительно "замечательная" замена `break` на `if(0)`. А  "необычность" всё же есть, ведь *обычно* так не пишут.

Answer (score 4):

> код явно с такой ошибкой, что даже компилироваться не должен

В коде нет никаких синтаксических ошибок, почему он не должен компилироваться? А с точки зрения логики обработки `switch` получается так:

```
if( a == 1 ) 
  goto label_case_1;
else 
  goto label_default;

label_case_1:
  r = "1";
  goto case_end;

if(0) { /* этот if никак не влияет на видимость метки */
label_default:
  r = "not 1";
}

case_end:
  puts(r);
```